# How to delete s3 bucket objects after 6 months from their creation with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

While setting the lifecycle expires rule for s3 bucket objects with terraform (s3 bucket already created earlier), i was facing error.

> Error creating S3 bucket: BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou: Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it.
>       status code: 409,

using terraform installed in vm-player

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "<<bucket_name>>"
  acl    = "private"

  lifecycle_rule {
    id      = "log"
    enabled = true
    prefix  = "log/log.txt"

    expiration {
      days = 180
    }
  }
}
```

It should create a lifecycle rule for log.txt file with expiration of 180 days.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the lifecycle rule (which should be fine from a quick glance). The error is telling you that you already have this S3 bucket in your AWS account. Either you need to import this into your state file or edit the S3 bucket configuration in the place where you created it.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR You should make this an answer so it can be accepted.